# How can I design one Linux file system?

Tags: filesystem, system

In an interview, I came across this question. He asked me "Design a linux file system." He asked to give what all things I would need, Data structures and all. Can anyone help me in this that how I can tackle this kind of problem? Just give me necessary links which I can read and refer. I have read on wikipedia but I am not still clear how to tackle this question perfectly. What he might be expecting? I want basic details which linux file system uses. How can I think of file system if I want to design one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a *huge* topic and it sounds like you're starting at the bottom. You need to understand what a filesystem *is* before you can hope to design one.

To the Kernel, a file or directory is just an *inode* tied to a *superblock*. The *inode* stores data location information as well as attributes about ownership, permissions, etc. That scopes out the data. Parallel to all this is a tree structure of *dentries*. These give filenames (hardlinks) and positions to *inodes*. Together links and nodes give you the filesystem that transforms from a path to naughts-and-ones.

That's a brutally quick skim but those are the elements you'd have to design. You can see from real examples (The Linux Kernel source is famously free) but there are some pretty decent documents out there:

- [Andries Brouwer: The Linux Virtual File System](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-8.html). Full-on but thorough.
- [Anatomy of the Linux file system](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-linux-filesystem/). Not as thorough but good related links.
- [TLDP: Virtual File systems](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/fs/filesystem.html) Very high level but explains what these elements actually *do*.

---

In practice though, if you needed to write a filesystem, you'd probably [turn to something like `fuse-python`](http://www.stavros.io/posts/python-fuse-filesystem/) and write one in an an afternoon. Not as performant as proper filesystems, but quick to write for many tasks.